# Incomplete Fermi-Integral to link solid and plasma: Did this autor make a mistake?

Tags: solid-state-physics, plasma-physics

At some point int his paper[1] the author defines a function:

$$f(T)=\int_\mu^\infty F(\epsilon,T)d\epsilon$$
where 
$$F(\epsilon)=\frac{g(\epsilon)}{1+e^{(\epsilon-\mu)/kT}} d\epsilon$$
and 
$$g(\epsilon)=\frac{2}{(2\pi^2)n_e}(\frac{2m}{\hbar^2})^{3/2}\sqrt\epsilon$$

For me this looks like the incomplete Fermi-integral. However, there's a problem: The chemical potential $\mu(T)$ becomes negative for $T\geq T_F$ (Fermi-temperature). The integral above cannot be evaluated for negative lower limits. So how can this hold?

Any hints?

[1]Europhysics Letters, Volume 108, Issue 5, article id. 53001 (2014).

DOI:http://dx.doi.org/10.1209/0295-5075/108/53001

Comment: $g(\epsilon)$ appears to have no $\epsilon$ dependence. Is this correct? If it is then you can eliminate $\mu$ with a change of variables

Comment: Thanks for the hint.g is the density of states and for 3D it has a sqrt(epsilon)-dependence of course (free-electron approximation)

Comment: First, what does a negative energy mean in this context?  Second, are you sure the $\mu$ is the chemical potential here (I have not read the paper)?